# Simple HTML tags to form elements - LinkedIn Profile editing

Tags: forms, plugins, linkedin-api

Is there any plugin that transfoms html elements (span, div) into a form ? One example is when editing LinkedIn profile which convert the section to be modified into a form.

Thanks all !

Comment: MVC has something like that with the rasor templates, using jQueru UI stuff. Have a look at JQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has the Wrap method, which you can use to throw the whole div / span into a form.

```
$('.inner').wrap('<form class="newform" action="..." method="..." />');
```

Found here: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Using .wrap(), we can insert an HTML structure around the inner  elements like so:

```
$('.inner').wrap('<div class="new" />');
```

The new  element is created on the fly and added to the DOM. The result is a new  wrapped around each matched element:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second version of this method allows us to instead specify a callback function. This callback function will be called once for every matched element; it should return a DOM element, jQuery object, or HTML snippet in which to wrap the corresponding element. For example:

```
$('.inner').wrap(function() {
  return '<div class="' + $(this).text() + '" />';
});
```

This will cause each  to have a class corresponding to the text it wraps:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="Hello">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Goodbye">
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Examples:
Example: Wrap a new div around all of the paragraphs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

  div { border: 2px solid blue; }
  p { background:yellow; margin:4px; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>cruel</p>
  <p>World</p>
<script>$("p").wrap("<div></div>");</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ShaunOReilly, that's was very helpfull !

Comment: Sounds like you still need more info?